# How to infer the specific return type of a method with a generic return type?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Given the following interface:

```
interface Random extends java.util.function.Supplier<Integer> { }
```

with `java.util.function.Supplier` looking like this (abbreviated):

```
public interface Supplier<T> { T get(); }
```

Now consider the following:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method get = Random.class.getMethod("get");
System.out.println(get.getReturnType()); // prints `class java.lang.Object`
System.out.println(get.getGenericReturnType()); // prints `T`
```

How can I infer that the return type should actually be `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this is potentially possible. Refer the link I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do this with something like below code. The idea here is that the generic type information is potentially available in the byte code and can be accessed at runtime. Refer the link below for more details.

```
ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) subClass.getGenericSuperclass();
09
  return (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[parameterIndex];
```

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/advanced-java-generics-retreiving-generic-type-arguments.html

There are some other useful articles online which describe this too.

Comment: I was thinking about something like that before - it is used by Google Guice to figure the type parameter. Problem is that in reality i don’t know anything about the class hierarchy or the method - this was just an example. So then it can get very complex to  impute the inference.

Comment: That’s a different question I believe, where Reflection API should be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Ankur's response is correct in that it provides a hint to the technology to use. However, a generic solution which covers all the edge cases is pretty complex, which justifies the need for a small library.

After researching the subject more, I have found this excellent solution: https://github.com/leangen/geantyref#getting-the-exact-return-type-of-a-method

Comment: Yep, my response was kind of narrowed down to the original question scope. Glad to know there is a library to extract the type parameter using this tech.