# Inferring type of class arguments in Java generic interface

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

**Please note:** I have spent an entire day ensuring that this is not a duplicate. Most solutions that I've seen rely on a call to `clazz.getGenericSuperclass()` followed by `getActualTypeArguments()`, but this doesn't solve my problem since the generic superclass is `java.lang.Object`.

Please read on.

---

**Now to the problem**

I would like to implement a library that offers a generic interface.

```java
public interface MyInterface<K, V> {
    public V get(K key);
    public void set(K key, V value);
}
```

Users might then implement it in a concrete class, e.g.:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ConcreteClass implements MyInterface<String, Integer> {
    private HashMap< String, Integer > myMap;

    public ConcreteClass() {
    this.myMap = new HashMap< >();
    }

    public Integer get(String key) {
    return myMap.get(key);
    }

    public void set(String key, Integer value) {
    myMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Or they might implement another generic class, e.g.:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GenericClass<K, V> implements MyInterface<K, V> {
    private HashMap<K, V> myMap;

    public GenericClass() {
    this.myMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }

    public V get(K key) {
    return myMap.get(key);
    }

    public void set(K key, V value) {
    myMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Now, I want the capability to infer the generic types of any instances of these classes. I'm trying to achieve this in `inferTypes` method in `Main.java`, as follows:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Main {
    private static <K, V> void inferTypes(MyInterface<K, V> mi) {
        Class<?> clazz = mi.getClass();

        // Should print whether "ConcreteClass" or "GenericClass"
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());

        Type[] ifaces = clazz.getGenericInterfaces();
        for (Type iface : ifaces) {
            // Should print "MyInterface<String, Integer>"
            System.out.println(iface.toString());
            Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType) iface).getActualTypeArguments();
            for (Type type : types) {
                // Should print "String" and then "Integer"
                System.out.println(type.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Someone instantiates the class
        ConcreteClass cc = new ConcreteClass();
        // And I can successfully infers the type
        Main.inferTypes(cc);

        System.out.println("-------");

        // Someone instantiates the generic class
        GenericClass<String, Integer> gc = new GenericClass<>();
        // And I can't infer the types this time
        Main.inferTypes(gc);
    }
}
```

It works with the instance of `ConcreteClass` but not with that of `GenericClass`.

```java
ConcreteClass
MyInterface<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
-------
GenericClass
MyInterface<K, V>
K
V
```

I cannot figure out how to get concrete classes for the second case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo, doesn't have any effect. Moreover, since these classes would be instantiated by the users of the library, I cannot enforce any particular manner of instantiation.

Comment: I assume you have already gone through this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690045/how-to-infer-the-specific-return-type-of-a-method-with-a-generic-return-type

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo, yes. As I mention in the note at the top. `getGenericSuperclass()` approach doesn't work since it returns an object of type `java.lang.Object` that I cannot cast to `ParameterizedType`. Gives me a compile time warning `unchecked cast`; and a runtime `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Yes, but I actually meant using the library https://github.com/leangen/geantyref#getting-the-exact-return-type-of-a-method .  It might be of help here.

Comment: I didn't know about this one. I'll check it out, thanks. But I'm not sure that it is available in my production environment. So I might have to keep looking for a solution using standard Java libraries.

Comment: May be try using this method of the Class class for the second case (separately) public TypeVariable<Class<T>>[] getTypeParameters()  i.e. if the class is of generic type itself, then use this method (ofcourse first try it separately for the second case and then think about generalization if it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `GenericClass<K, V>` there is no information in the class file which determines the type. This is due to type erasure.

The best you can do is infer the type from the contents of the Map.  If you need to record the type you can do

```
public class GenericClass<K, V> implements MyInterface<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> myMap;
    private final Class<K> keyClass;
    private final Class<V> valueClass

    public GenericClass(Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass) {
        this.myMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }

    public Class<K> getKeyClass() { return keyClass; }
    public Class<V> getValueClass() { return valueClass; }
```

i.e. you need to store the types explicitly.

Comment: and just to add, if your design relies on this then 9 times of 10 the design is just wrong.

Comment: @Michael I have used it, but only in very specific cases. e.g. making serialization more compact.

Comment: @Michael, could you please elaborate? Because as Peter adds in his comment, I need this inference to ensure type safety during serialisation.

Comment: @N.CHATURV3DI It *might* be necessary, but the number of times people ask how to do things like this on Stack Overflow vs. how often it's actually desirable/necessary/optimal are worlds apart.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, since my interface is provided as a library, I cannot ensure that users implementing this interface would create these fields in their classes. I've "heard" of type erasure, but I thought it only applied to built-in Java generics like `Map`, `List`, etc. Are you sure there's no other way?

Comment: @N.CHATURV3DI type erasure applies to all types.  If you want to ensure implementers of the interface can return the types, add method(s) to the interface they have to implement.

Comment: @N.CHATURV3DI When you create a class which implements a generic type, you are creating a new class, and it's the information for that class you are retrieving.